# Strange generics behavior in swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, generics

Good day!

I am currently trying to learn programming swift and trying some examples of generics. Here is my example code

```
func findAll<T: Equatable>(arr: [T], _ elem: T) -> [Int] {
    var indexesArr = [Int]()
    var counter = 0

    for i in arr {
        if i == elem {
           indexesArr.append(counter)
        }
        counter++
    }

    return indexesArr
}

findAll([5, 3, 7, 3, 9], 3)
findAll(["a", "b", "c", "b", "d"], 2.0)
```

It was supposed, that both arguments will be of the same type. But, unfortunately, as you can see I pass an array of string characters and a Double in my second function invocation and it still works! It returns an empty array []. No runtime or compile errors.

Please, explain me why it works and some workarounds maybe. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have `import Cocoa` or `import Foundation` in your code somewhere. If you remove that, you'll find that your code behaves as you're expecting.

The reason this happens is that importing Foundation causes `Swift.Array` to magically bridge to `NSArray` (aka `[AnyObject]`), and certain primitive value types to magically bridge to Foundation object types (like `NSString` and `NSNumber`). Once that happens, it's perfectly legal to call your function with parameters of types `[AnyObject]` and `AnyObject`.

---

I'm not aware of a *good* way around the magic conversion, but one way that works is to force your generic parameter to have a protocol that primitive value types conform to, but primitive values magically wrapped in Cocoa objects don't. One way to assure such is to create your own protocol:

```
public protocol NotAnyObject {}
extension Int: NotAnyObject {}
extension String: NotAnyObject {}
extension Double: NotAnyObject {}
func findAll<T: Equatable where T: NotAnyObject>(arr: [T], _ elem: T) -> [Int] { /*...*/ }
```

I'm not sure this is the best way, though... alternative proposals are welcome.

---

By the way, a more idiomatic/Swifty way to do something like this would be as a type extension (either a protocol extension, as below, or an extension on `Array where Element: Equatable`). You can even go functional-programming-style just for fun:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    public func allIndexesOf(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> [Self.Index] {
        return zip(self.indices, self) // makes sequence of (index, element)
            .filter { $0.1 == element } 
            .map { $0.0 }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
let threes = [5, 3, 7, 3, 9].allIndexesOf(3)
// returns [1, 3]
```

This is still subject to the same magic conversions issue, though:

```
let notThrees = ["twenty", "forty", "eight"].allIndexesOf[2.0]
// still compiles, returns []
```

So you'd still need to either use this extension only from Swift files that don't import Foundation, or apply a variant of the same hack as above, e.g.:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element: Equatable,
    Generator.Element: NotAnyObject { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: I agree with the explanation, I don't agree with the proposed solution, removing `Foundation` imports is usually impossible.

Comment: Great thanks to rickster and @Sulthan ! Both answers really helped me! Tried to upvote both, but looks like stackoverflow thinks in another way :)

Comment: This bridging really makes me sad :/ Do such issues really bother while developing IOS applications? Oh it's just a thing to know about, but not really a problem?

Comment: Probably worth [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about. Bridging is nice when you want to pass collections of primitive values to/from Cocoa APIs without lots of wrap/unwrap boilerplate. I imagine getting that without making it overzealous takes some tweaking.

Answer (score -1):

For the problem explanation see [rickster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35659975/669586)

Note that to solve problems like this, you can always just check how Swift libraries do it. The solution is to have both arguments as generics and using protocol constraints.

E.g. using `SequenceType` protocol instead of an `Array`.

```
func findAll<S: SequenceType, T: Equatable where S.Generator.Element == T>(arr: S, _ elem: T) -> [Int] {
    var indexesArr = [Int]()
    var counter = 0

    for i in arr {
        if i == elem {
            indexesArr.append(counter)
        }
        counter++
    }

    return indexesArr
}
```

Comment: `findAll(["a", "b", "c", "b", "d"], 2.0)` still compiles and runs (and returns an empty array) with this.

Comment: @rickster You are right but the cause of the problem changes. Now is caused by the fact that you are using literal values only so the types are inferred to `[AnyObject]`. However, inferring problems can be easily solved using `findAll(["a", "b", "c", "b", "d"], 2.0 as Double)` or `findAll(["a", "b", "c", "b", "d"] as [String], 2.0)`. In most cases you would have the array declared beforehand in a variable.